# Slow loading of XML layout - ViewStub

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

One of my xml layouts has 1702 lines of code. Problem is slow loading. I have tried divide xml into two layouts and load first containing some textviews (very fast) + ViewStub with second layout (contains images and lot of data). Even if ViewStub's visibility is gone, loading takes same ammount of time as before dividing.

Is there any way, how to open fast intent with first layout and after that, start loading second layout?

Comment: 1702 lines of xml is too much. You should think about optimizing your layout, rather than how to load it faster

Comment: It's optimized as much as possible. There is just too many people with some informations...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, strongly consider reorganizing your information to be navigable by clicks rather than trying to display everything in giant view hierarchy.

If you're displaying a list of items, use a RecyclerView to limit the number of views created at a time to what can actually be displayed.

If you're feeling brave, you can try to inflate views in a background thread and send the results to the main thread for adding to the view hierarchy, but I don't recommend that.

If none of these solutions is OK, then I don't think you'll be able to get any help, because you have designed something that is not friendly for mobile development.  You can't simply copy the way you do things in desktop and web development because mobile devices are constrained in resources and screen size.